# creating a custom gradle task to source mysql schema

Tags: java, mysql, gradle, mysql-connector

I'm trying to write a custom `Gradle` task that would source `mysql` create and insert statements from a .sql file. This is what I've come up with :-

```
task initdb() {
    def mysql = buildscript.configurations.classpath.find { it.toString().contains("mysql-connector-java") }
//    URLClassLoader loader = GroovyObject.class.classLoader

    def db = [url: "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/",
              user: "root", password: "admin", driver: 'com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver']
    def sql = groovy.sql.Sql.newInstance(db.url, db.user, db.password, db.driver)
}
```

I'm getting an error saying Driver class not found. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

The classpath of a Gradle task and the classpaths of your project are not the same thing.
Also the configuration and the execution of a Gradle task are two different things.

You would need the following:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral() // assuming your driver can be found there, if not, a custom repository
    }
    dependencies {
        // Add the driver, and its dependencies, to the buildscript classpath
        classpath "<driver dependency coordinates>"
    }
}

task initdb() {
    doLast {// Make sure the code is run during execution phase and not configuration phase
        def mysql = buildscript.configurations.classpath.find { it.toString().contains("mysql-connector-java") }
        //    URLClassLoader loader = GroovyObject.class.classLoader

        def db = [url: "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/",
          user: "root", password: "admin", driver: 'com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver']
        def sql = groovy.sql.Sql.newInstance(db.url, db.user, db.password, db.driver)
    }
}
```